# O que significa "Usuário não registrado"?

Tags: suporte, contas-usuário

Por exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/7918/maria

Tem como criar uma pergunta sem criar uma conta? Se é possível, por quanto tempo o usuário fica logado? Se ele deslogar uma vez, nunca mais ele consegue logar de novo na mesma conta? Isso não aumentaria a quantidade de perguntas sem respostas aceitas? Já que o usuário não se cadastrou, ele pode nem saber que responderam a pergunta dele.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Tem como criar uma pergunta sem criar uma conta?

**Sim.** Ao tentar fazer uma pergunta sem estar logado, os campos de pergunta abrem normalmente. Abaixo deles, você tem a opção de logar ou postar como "convidado", bastando deixar nome e email:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

<sup>*Required, but não exibido* é pra rir...</sup>

A principal diferença é que um usuário não registrado não tem credenciais de login associada a ele. Efetivamente isso que dizer que não sabemos quem é você (exceto por ter o IP utilizado e o nome e email fornecidos) e que o seu perfil enfrenta algumas restrições.

No StackOverflow.com e em alguns outros sites do SE, usuários não registrados não podem fazer perguntas, apenas responder.

> Se é possível, por quanto tempo o usuário fica logado? Se ele deslogar uma vez, nunca mais ele consegue logar de novo na mesma conta?

É baseado em cookies. Quando você desloga a gente te lembra de registrar (fora alguns outros lembretes), mas se você fizer logout sem registrar existe a opção de [Recuperação da conta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/account-recovery) e possivelmente fazer um merge das contas para ganhar acesso ao perfil não registrado. Após recuperado, o perfil é registrado para evitar outra perda de acesso.

> Isso não aumentaria a quantidade de perguntas sem respostas aceitas?

Talvez. Mas isso também facilita o processo de atrair novos usuários que não têm que assumir um compromisso logo de cara com o site. Se eles gostarem sempre existe a possibilidade de recuperar o acesso e se tornar um usuário devidamente registrado.

Baseado em: [How do unregistered accounts work?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/262909/1964435)

Comment: Ok, talvez minha pergunta tenha sido um pouco pobre pois eu não sabia a resposta, mas agora que sei me levantaram várias outras dúvidas (tipo aqueles usuários chatos que te exploram, rsrs). Já que é possível criar uma pergunta sem criar conta, por quanto tempo o usuário fica logado? Se ele deslogar uma vez, nunca mais ele consegue logar de novo na mesma conta? Isso não aumenta a quantidade de perguntas sem respostas aceitas? Já que o usuário não se cadastrou, ele pode nem saber que responderam a pergunta dele.

Comment: Não faço a menor ideia! Mas vou pesquisar e voltou depois com a informação.

Comment: Fizeram a msm pergunta no so.com, veja: [How do unregistered accounts work?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/262909/1964435)

Comment: @Math Transformei a resposta em CW, fique à vontade para complementá-la :)

Comment: Blz! Farei amanhã ;)

Comment: Ok, ontem não deu.. mas deixa comigo